# Koszul applied to dimension theory

Tags: krull-dimension

Reading on the proof in Atiyah-MacDonald (A-M) of the main theorem of dimension theory, I realized that the inductive step in all three of the inequalities
$$
\delta(A) \ge d(A) \ge \dim A \ge \delta(A) 
$$
uses a non-zero divisor of $A$ to drop one dimension lower. I know that the definitions in A-M generalize to finitely generated modules over semi-local noetherian rings, in which case this non-zero divisor becomes a non-zero divisor of $M$, i.e. an element $a \in A$ which does not annihilate any $m \in M \setminus \{0\}$.

My question is : I am not comfortable yet with the homological techniques of Koszul, but does knowledge of that theory allow some over-kill proof of the main theorem of dimension theory, or is the work in any case still necessary? (And of course, a second part to this question is : has this been done somewhere?)

Comment: The Koszul complex detects depth, but not dimension. So you seem lost in the non Cohen-Macaulay case.

Comment: @Moos : What about the Cohen-Macaulay case? That could still give some general insight as to "why the dimension theorem is true".